# Use of the phrase "tangent vector of a curve"

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, notation

Let us understand a *curve* as a differentiable map $f : J \to \mathbb R^n$ defined on an open interval $J \subset \mathbb R$. The derivative $f'(t_0)$ of $f$ at $t_0 \in J$ is given as the vector $(f'_1(t_0),\ldots,f'_n(t_0)) \in \mathbb R^n$ where the $f_i : J \to \mathbb R$ are the coordinate functions of $f$.

I think for $n > 1$ it is usual to say that $f'(t_0)$ is the *tangent vector to the curve $f$ at the point $t_0$* or  the *velocity vector of the curve $f$ at the point $t_0$*.

For $n = 1$ one can find the wording *velocity vector*, but I have never seen that $f'(t_0)$ is called the *tangent vector* of $f  :J \to \mathbb R$ at $t_0$. The definition of the derivative $f'(t_0)$ as the limit $\lim_{t \to t_0}\dfrac{f(t)-f(t_0)}{t-t_0}$ is nevertheless motivated by the *concept of tangent* by saying that $f'(t_0)$ is the slope of the tangent of the graph $G(f) = \{(t,f(t)) \mid t \in J \} \subset \mathbb R^2$ at the point $(t_0,f(t_0))$. There is also a notational relation to the case $n > 1$: If we consider the curve $\bar f : J \to \mathbb R^2, \bar f(t) = (t,f(t))$, then we get $f'(t_0)$ as the second coordinate of the tangent vector $\bar f'(t_0) \in \mathbb R^2$.

Finally, if we consider a smooth ($C^\infty$) curve $f$ and a point $t_0 \in J$ such that $f'(t_0) \ne 0$, then $M  = f(J)$ is locally around $p_0 = f(t_0)$ a smooth one-dimensional submanifold of $\mathbb R^n$. It has a tangent space $T_{p_0}M$ at $p_0$ which we may regard as a one-dimensional linear subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ and *all* $v \in T_{p_0}M$ are called *tangent vectors at $M$ at $p_0$*. This suggests that all scalar multiples of the tangent vector $f'(t_0)$ can also be regarded as tangent vectors (which appears reasonable to me).

I find this notationally confusing. The word "tangent vector" seems to have various different interpretations, but in the most elementary case $n = 1$ it is not used. Would it be better to avoid using the name "tangent vector" for $f'(t_0)$, but to use the unambiguous "velocity vector"? Perhaps somebody can help me to clarify my disorientation.

Comment: People don't typically think of points of $\mathbb{R}$ as "vectors," so they may not use that terminology in elementary courses, but there is absolutely nothing wrong in doing so.

Comment: I try to keep the following distinction: The derivative is a linear map, and a tangent vector is any vector in the image of that map. This helps me keep clear what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your confusion comes from mixing two different situations where the phrase "tangent vector" occurs. These are

1. Tangent vectors of curves $f : J \to \mathbb R^n$.
2. Tangent vectors at points of smooth submanifolds $M \subset \mathbb R^n$.

Perhaps the concept of *curve* is a bit ambiguous, sometimes it is used in the sense of a (differentiable) *map* $f : J \to \mathbb R^n$ and sometimes in the sense of a certain *subset* of some Euclidean space. The latter is often given as the image of some $f : J \to \mathbb R^n$, but it can also have an implicit description as the set of solutions of an algebraic equation (for example, $x^2(x+a) + y^2(x-a) = 0$ yields the *strophoid* in the plane). Curves in the subset sense need not be one-dimensional submanifolds of $\mathbb R^n$, they may e.g. have "self-intersections". But *locally* they are one-dimensional submanifolds of $\mathbb R^n$ and therefore it suffices to discuss 1. and 2.

Let us look at 1. As you say

> For  $n > 1$ it is usual to say that $f'(t_0)$ is the *tangent vector to the curve $f$ at the point $t_0$* or  the *velocity vector of the curve $f$ at the point $t_0$*.

The concept of *velocity vector* is related to the physical interpretation via a moving particle. The concept of *tangent vector* is more geometrical, and in fact one might argue that calling $f'(t_0)$ **the tangent vector** to $f$ at $t_0$ is a bit too possessive because it seems to claim that $f'(t_0)$ is the only tangent vector. But of course we get a *tangent line* to $f$ at $p_0 = f(t_0)$ and all non-zero scalar multiples of $f′(t_0)$ can also be regarded as tangent vectors. Clearly $f'(t_0)$ spans the one-dimensional tangent line, but does it have a more convincing unique feature? Probably not from the geometric point of view, but clearly from the functional point of view. Recall that $f$ encodes much more information than its image $f(J)$. The *parameterized affine line* $\tau(t) = f(t_0) + (t-t_0)f'(t_0)$ is the best approximation of $f$ at $t_0$.

This is not visible when looking globally at the tangent line and $f(J)$, but in terms of functions it is obvious. And that is the difference between 1. and 2.: For one-dimensional submanifolds it does not make sense to pick out a single tangent vector, all are on a par.

I suggest that you accept the phrase "**the** tangent vector" of a curve as a standard notation used only in context with parameterization. Doing so, **each** tangent vector $v$ at a point $p$ of a smooth submanifold $M \subset \mathbb R^n$ occurs as **the** tangent vector $f'(0)$ of a curve $f : J \to \mathbb R^n$ with $0 \in J, f(0) = p$ and $f(J) \subset M$. Of course $f$ is not uniquely determined by $v$, but you certainly know that this relation between tangent vectors $v$ and curves $f$ can be used to define the tangent space $T_pM$ of an abstract manifold $M$ via equivalence classes of curves through $p$.

Concerning the case $n = 1$:

The concept of ["tangent"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent) was originally only used for plane curves. Heuristically

> the tangent line (or simply tangent) to a plane curve at a given point is the straight line that "just touches" the curve at that point.

This is why the derivative of a real-valued function $f$ was introduced by considering its graph which is a special plane curve.  Anyway, the concept of tangent easily generalizes to curves $f$ in $\mathbb R^n$ with arbitrary $n > 1$. The tangent to $f$ at  $t_0$ is the parameterized affine line which is the best approximation of $f$ at $t_0$. As the curve itself this affine line is a *one-dimensional* object embedded in a *higher-dimensional* Euclidean space which makes it non-trivial to associate tangents to curves.

For $n = 1$ it is fairly pointless to consider tangent lines since the real line $\mathbb R$ itself is the only line contained in $\mathbb R$. Thus each curve in $\mathbb R$ has the real line as its tangent line in all of its points, which is a triviality. This is certainly the reason why one usually does not call $f'(t_0) \in \mathbb R$ tangent vector. But *formally* we can of course do it.

Answer (score 3):

I think this comes from differential geometry. Let's say you have a smooth manifold $M$ embedded in $R^n$, for example the sphere. Then one defines the tangent space at as the vector space of directions tangent to $M$. For example if
$$
M = F^{-1}(0)
$$
For some nice function $F : \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$ then the tangent space will be the kernel of the map
$$
v \mapsto \nabla_vF
$$
Where $(\nabla_v F)_i = \sum\frac{\partial F_i}{\partial x_j}v_j$. These are the directions you can move in while staying on the manifold, that is, the tangent space.

A curve is a one dimensional manifold, and so the tangent space at a point in the curve is just a one dimensional vector space (assuming nonzero velocity) and hence the tangent vector is the vector which spans this tangent space.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But it does not really what I wanted to understand.  At any point  $p  \in M  \subset \mathbb R^n$ we have a whole *vector space* of tangent vectors. If $\dim M = 1$, then this is a one-dimensional vector space and all of its elements are called tangent vectors. But if $M$ is  (locally) parameterized by $f : J \to \mathbb R^n$, then one says that $f'(p)$ is **the  tangent vector**. Of course it spans the tangent space,  but my notational confusion is the discrepancy between the number of vectors called tangent vectors: Infinitely many vs. a unique one.

Comment: I suppose one argument would be that if you're thinking about vectors tangent to the curve then you maybe don't really care about its magnitude, so you could say something like it is the tangent vector up to scaling, but this vector is particularly easy to write down and is the most useful (eg when calculating the length of the curve) so is in some sense the canonical tangent vector to the curve. In any case, I don't think this discrepancy causes that much confusion.

Comment: You are right, $f'(p)$ is the only reasonable association of a tangent vector to $f$. Any scaled variant would involve an arbitrary choice.

Comment: @PaulFrost Wouldn't the unit tangent vector $f'(p)/\lVert f'(p) \rVert$ be a good choice?

Comment: @KritikerderElche In a sense yes, but note that the unit tangent vector depends on the choice of  a norm on $\mathbb R^n$. Usually one takes the Euclidean norm, but there are many other choices. It is well-known that all norms on $\mathbb R^n$ are equivalent, but this does not mean that they produce the same unit vectors. The vector $f'(p)$ is defined by componentwise differentiating, thus does not depend on the choice of a norm.